# Undef'ing a function-like macro

Tags: c-preprocessor

In the **C**/C++ there are 2 types of macro:

```
 #define ABC   /* usual */
```

und

```
 #define FUNC(a)  /*function-like*/
```

But how can I undefine them?

Update: So there is no difference between undefing "constant-like macro" and "function-like macro"?

Comment: If I have '#Define abc' and '#Define abc(A)', both of them will be undefed with one '#undef abc' ?

Comment: There is nu such thing a macro overloading. After you second `#define` of `abc`, the first one will be gone.

Comment: Job, I think you are wrng. Both constant-like and function like macro can coexist. Also, function-like macroses with different number of params can coexist too

Comment: @osgx: Nope I'm sorry but *you* are wrong.

Comment: The second `#define ABC` is invalid (unless the new definition is identical to the old one, which it isn't here). Some dodgy preprocessors might allow it; others will give warnings or errors.

Comment: @osgx: maybe you have a non-compliant preprocessor which allows macro overloads, but a compliant one won't. We can't really answer a question on how a non-compliant implementation behaves.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
#undef ABC
#undef FUNC
```

[`#undef` "cancels" out a previous `#define`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/). The effect is as though you never had a previous `#define` for a particular identifier. Do note that `#define`s do not respect scope, so it's best to use them only when you need to.

Also note that it doesn't matter if one macro identifier uses the "usual" syntax while another uses a "function-like" syntax. `#define ABC` and `#define ABC(A)` both define a macro named `ABC`. If you have both, without `#undef`ing one of them, the latest one "overrides" the other. (Some compilers may emit a warning if this happens.)

Comment: LOL. I knew that was going to happen:-)

Answer (score 13):

```
#undef ABC
#undef FUNC
```

Comment: 2 seconds apart.  If this were a race you'd be a winner. ;p

Comment: Another case of the Fastest Gun in the West problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem ;-)